# Datagridview Dynamic Buttons text disappearing after header sort

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When sorting the datagridview by clicking on any of my headers my button text disappears

```
var MoreInfoCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
MoreInfoCol.Name = "MoreInfoColumn";
MoreInfoCol.HeaderText = "Extended Description";
dataGRID.Columns.Add(MoreInfoCol);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGRID.Rows)
{
row.Cells["MoreInfoColumn"].Value = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + " | More Info";
dataGRID.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGRID_CellContentClick);                                        
}
```

Comment: Only add the the CellContentClick event once.  You are adding it for every row so it will run multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
MoreInfoCol.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true; 
MoreInfoCol.Text = "My Value Goes here";
```